# How to make a report after a ddos attack? what information do I need to write on the report?

Tags: attacks, incident-response, ddos

In my company, after a DDOS against a server, my employer asked me to make an analysis of the attack and to write down some stuff.

What do you think I need to write down in my report?
Is there any available template from a CIRT or another organization that can be used after an incident?
What is the best practice about this kind of report?

In my first analysis i found where the attack was planned (an IRC channel).
I found information about the tool used and the url where the tool can be downloaded.
The attack is made with a LOIC and not with any kind of botnet (as I actually know).
The attack was planned without a hierarchical organization but was organized and maded with the help of people recruited hand-to-hand with the sharing of a little manifesto and the sharing through IRC and twitter of a JPG containing the information on the target and the time of the attack.
I need also to write down some stuff about the people around this attack?

any suggestion?

**PLEASE: one-suggestion one-answer, so we can have a community best practice at the end :)**

Comment: I think a useful field would be total down time and also cost estimates of missed orders and repair costs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry not to have a good link, but my thought is you want to cover:

**What happened?**

- When did it happen, and for how long did it continue?
- Who did it and how?
- What was affected - what sites, what servers, how many servers, what part of the business?  What customers?
- Root Cause Analysis

**What was the impact?**

- Damage to servers
- Damage/exposure of information
- Damage to corporate reputation
- Damage to human life (crossing fingers that this is a definite no!!!)
- Cost of Recovery (Time, Equipment, etc.)

**Halting/Preventing**

- What has been done so far?  Break it down into immediate response vs. ongoing updates
- What else should be done?
- What is the projection for this happening again?
- What about something like this, but not exactly the same?
- Are there any changes we could make to future process to prevent/mitigate this type of risk?

Break into past/present/future - what did we do immediate, what are we doing now, what are the big things we should do in the future that will require high level funding?

**Future Prognosis**

- If we do everything in the report what is the likely state of the system to future attacks.  Probably not "bulletproof", so give some assessment of likelihood.
- How about if we just leave the system in it's current (partially fixed?) state?

Comment: +1, I would also add root cause analysis, and also under impact - time personnel spent cleaning up the mess...

Comment: @Avid - Thanks, good call, I made the update in the answer.

Comment: well, then, I'd +1 you again, if I could... ;-)

Comment: @Autocracy karma comes around

Comment: @bethlakshmi: thanks for the good answer. Right now I found a guidelines from NIST about incident response after DDOS. An answer from myself come soon, i hope.

Comment: Excellent answer, very thorough. +1.